# Some of the "unanswered" questions don't really deserve that title

Tags: discussion

I've been browsing the unanswered questions, partly because [Area 15](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino) says:

> 71% answered: Needs Work – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work.

However I've found some "unanswered" questions really **were** answered, for example:

- [Crash when using std::queue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12127/crash-when-using-stdqueue). That had a perfectly good answer by Edgar Bonet, however he did it as a comment, not an answer so it didn't count.
- [What could cause interrupts from MCP23017 suddenly stop working?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/what-could-cause-interrupts-from-mcp23017-suddenly-stop-working) - the OP worked out the problem and acknowledged that in a comment, however the question went "unanswered".
- [Attiny85 programmer with Arduino error Yikes! Invalid device signature](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10321/attiny85-programmer-with-arduino-error-yikes-invalid-device-signature) - again, answered in the question comments, and acknowledged as such by the OP.
- [After putting Arduino Uno into DFU mode, it is no longer recognised by PC](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11863/after-putting-arduino-uno-into-dfu-mode-it-is-no-longer-recognised-by-pc) - the OP is asked for clarification but doesn't respond so the question lapses.

It seems to me unfair that these questions go into the "29% unanswered" bundle when they really were answered, or the OP simply lost interest (probably got it answered somewhere else).

Does this seem right? Is there a way of fixing up these statistics in some way?

Comment: *Attiny85 programmer with Arduino error Yikes! Invalid device signature* - I don't think that one ever got answered as the OP was vague as to what worked and then went on to buy a proper programmer. Note I was commenting there.

Answer (score 6):

In cases where there's already an answer in the comments (or edited into the original question by the OP), we could copy it into a [Community Wiki](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) answer, with an appropriate acknowledgement. That will show up as an answer, but will prevent reputation going to the wrong person.

In situations where a question can't be answered due to lack of information (and the OP hasn't responded for a long time), we can vote to close the question as "Unclear what you're asking".

These steps won't solve the problem entirely, but it might help a little. What's important is to get the community involved in Review tasks so that problems can be dealt-with quickly. The other moderators and I aren't really supposed to do that ourselves (we're only supposed to deal with exceptional cases). I see the review queues are getting rather long again though, so we may have to step in to help things move along.

Comment: I've always suggested the OP make their comment an answer so others can find it more easily. They can get the reputation, as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins

Comment: Cleaning up these ild questions will make the site look cleaner, and I think that will help longer-term to improve the review process.